# Coercing a silver dragon

Tags: adnd-2e, alignment, dragons

Could a silver dragon mom fearing the death of her unhatched offspring **ever** be coerced into giving blood?

Example:
A chaotic good, extremely powerful, highly charismatic, and boosted by potions extra wise and smart Bard (and his party) was rudely coerced by the dragon into saving it's eggs. When stealth failed, an entire city of intelligent but evil creatures was destroyed to return the eggs. The reward offered by the ancient dragon isn't useful. The dragon's blood however could to be used to create an "evil" artifact, that the bard intends to use it for good causes.
Neither the rudeness nor the potential good cause warrants the dragon's death - but the buffed bard hides the eggs, returns with just one and offers safe return of the remaining eggs in return for a small blood donation.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is primarily a question for your DM. This question is entirely opinion based and has been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like a Baldur's Gate 2 quest in the Drow City Ust Natha. The eggs of the Silver Dragon Andalon were stolen, and she protects the player's party with an illusion to look like drow in order to get her eggs back.

Regardless, your question as presented seems to have a flaw. A good creature would not use an evil artifact 'for good causes'. So the bard seems to already toy with evil before he ransoms her eggs - a clearly evil act.

It seems very unlikely that a lawful good silver dragon would ever enter into a deal with an evil bard - not even to save her own eggs.

Comment: Haha, well recognized, that is the situation it's based on. I'm not sure I agree with the good creature (if you mean the bard) wouldn't use evil artifact thing... High Level Ability to Use Any Item (regardless of class, alignment, race and other restrictions) is a class feature for bards in Baldur's Gate. Do you know of any (semi)official source that says chaotic good wouldn't use evil methods? Lying, manipulating, intimidating, etc. are great for getting neutrals to do participate in important causes...

If you meant the lawful good dragon being hesitant to participate in that, I understand.

Comment: BG2 is a great game, but it's different in many ways from tabletop RPGs and how things would be handled there. I don't have a source, it's just how I would handle it as DM - a good guy that uses evil is at least toying with it, and faces a great chance to be corrupted by it. Alignment questions are notoriously hard to source (and answer), since the way D&D presents them they are neither complete nor fully consistent, add to that that there are differences between editions...

Answer (score 0):

If personality does not vary this dragon is "lawfully good" and how she behaves becomes an alignment question. 
If personality does vary between dragons of the same type, then it would depend on the circumstances.

Assuming personalities can differ in this example they might take a long term approach (i.e. artifact could later fall into evil hands), or be too proud to give into demands.